# How to make stock Register with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have two pandas Dataframe of a Location which at some point receive at dispatch certain Item.

```
#Item Received 'tolo'
ID Date         Challan No  From Location    To Location  Item Quantity Remark
7  2021-09-16        124         Admin  dkl-kunjakant    pipe      500    hji
10  2021-09-01        345         Admin  dkl-kunjakant   pipe     1000    ert

#Item Dispatched 'frlo'
ID     Date    Challan No  From Location    To Location  Item Quantity Remark
3  2021-09-01        236  dkl-kunjakant  Dkl-deulasahi  pipe      145    asa
8  2021-09-24         10  dkl-kunjakant  Dkl-deulasahi  pipe       50    hji
9  2021-09-23        540  dkl-kunjakant  Dkl-deulasahi  pipe       40    rty
```

My objective is to calculate closing Balance at the end of certain date.
To calculate closing balance the formula is simple

```
Previous day Clsoing Bal + Received - Dispatched = Current day closing balance
```

For this my code have to iterate through each row of dataframe and calculate closing balance of each day. my code:

```
            frames = [tolo, frlo]
            result = pd.concat(frames)
            result['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(result.Date)
            result.sort_values(by='Date')
            main_columns = ['Date', 'Opening Stock', 'Received', 'Total', 'Dispatched', 'Closing Balance', 'Challan No', 'Remarks']
            main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=main_columns)
            for col in main_df.columns:
                main_df[col].values[:] = 0
            main_df['Date'] = result['Date']
            main_df['Challan No'] = result['Challan No']
            for _, row in result.iterrows():
                # print(row['c1'], row['c2'])
                # main_df['Date'] = row['Date']
                if row['To Location'] == godown_name:
                    main_df['Received'] = row['Quantity']
                    main_df['Remarks'] = row['To Location']
                elif row['From Location'] == godown_name:
                    main_df['Dispatched'] = row['Quantity']
                    main_df['Remarks'] = row['From Location']
            for _, row in main_df.iterrows():
                row['Opening Stock'] = row['Closing Balance'].shift()
                row['Total'] = row['Opening Stock'] + row['Received']
                row['Closing Balance'] = row['Total'] - row['Dispatched']
            print(main_df.head())
```

But by iterating through rows it throws me Attribute error in the pandas shift function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *circular dependency*: Opening Stock is dependent on Closing Stock, and Stock Stock is in turn dependent on Opening Stock. This is unsolvable. You have to calculate one variable another way.

Also you can replaced a lot of your code with *vectorized code*:. Try this:

```py
main_df = pd.concat([tolo, frlo])
main_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(main_df['Date'])
main_df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)

godown_name = 'dkl-kunjakant' # I may get this wrong
cond = main_df['To Location'] == godown_name
main_df['Received']   = np.where(cond, main_df['Quantity'], 0)
main_df['Dispatched'] = np.where(cond, 0, main_df['Quantity'])
main_df['Remarks']    = np.where(cond, main_df['To Location'], main_df['From Location'])

main_df['Closing Balance'] = (main_df['Received'] - main_df['Dispatched']).cumsum()
main_df['Opening Stock'] = main_df['Closing Balance'].shift(fill_value=0)
main_df['Total'] = main_df['Opening Stock'] + main_df['Received']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response But it throws me `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'` in the line of  `main_df['Closing Balance'] = (main_df['Received'] - main_df['Dispatched']).cumsum()`.

Comment: Both of them are coming out of the Quantity column. Does Quantity contain any weird values such as text or blank strings?

Comment: No It contains only numbers in integer format .

Comment: Can’t see your actual data so I can’t debug it. But Dispatched contains a string

Comment: after converting the quantity column to numeric format with this code: `pd.to_numeric(main_df['Quantity'], errors='coerce')` it still throws me the same error.